# pip package "pillow" is installed but not working

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, pip, python-imaging-library

This is an error message when I executed '*`python3 manage.py makemigrations`*'

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:
ERRORS:
main.Room.photo: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
    HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "python -m pip install Pillow".
```

But I installed `Pillow`.
When I typed `pip list`, there is `Pillow 8.1.0`.

Why Pillow is not working?

`pip version : 20.3.3`

`django version : 3.1.5`

`python3 version : 3.7.3`

`pillow version : 8.1.0``

***I have done :***

1. `PYTHONPATH` setting `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages`
2. `pip uninstall Pillow` & `pip install Pillow`

Comment: Did you use `pip3 install pillow`? Perhaps you installed pillow for python 2 instead of python 3?

Comment: Open the python shell by typing `python3` then in the shell type `import pillow` if that works piillow is succesfully installed otherwise it isnt